# How to test re-renderings of components in a React app in order to avoid performance regressions?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library

I am working on a medium scale React/redux application. On a few occasions in the past, I have measured performance, and reduced expensive component rendering when possible. That is, when I look into it manually.

There is always a time where something is lagging and I realize some earlier commit caused a performance regression because it caused part of the tree to re-render too often. So, I would like to avoid those regressions, for example in the integration tests of my app. How can I do that?

I was thinking of the following integration test, to be run on relevant app pages/states:

- Mount / visit app / go to relevant state
- Wait for loading of relevant data / initialization of the app
- Trigger an action that is mutating the root redux state (`state => { ...state }`) or anything that is:

  1. happening often; and
  2. should not cause any re-rendering.
- Detect any re-rendering of components down the tree

This is the last point that I'm interested in.

That sounds quite simple but I'm not sure how to do that. I'd like to see a generic answer to that, regardless of what testing tools are used.

Also, this question is redux-oriented, but I guess its relevance extends to whatever is causing re-rendering, should you wish to measure/test that.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid performance regressions, there's no necessity to detect re-renderings. Just measure the performance. See https://reactjs.org/docs/perf.html .

Comment: Well, my question _is_ about re-renderings automatic testing, which I'd like to detect, but you're right about more general performance investigations (although the link you provide is obsoleted by https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#profiling-components-with-the-chrome-performance-tab)